# TableView Section Change Header Alignment

Tags: swift, text, alignment, tableview

I have This `tableView` Here :[image: TableView Section Header Example]

With the default left text alignment which i would like to change to a right text alignment . How can i do this ?

## **EDIT:**

Now it looks like this :
[image: How It Looks Now]

Comment: Are you working with Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: @GeorgeH Swift 2.3

Comment: @GeorgeH I have some weird spacing issue can you try and help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do this in UITableView Datasource method  `viewForHeaderInSection`:

**Swift 2.3:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerText = UILabel()
    headerText.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    headerText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    switch section{
    case 0:
        headerText.textAlignment = .Center
        headerText.text = "This Header Will Be Centered"
    case 1:
        headerText.textAlignment = .Right
        headerText.text = "This Header Will Be Aligned Right"
    default:
        headerText.textAlignment = .Left
        headerText.text = "Default Will Be Left"
    }

    return headerText
}
```

EDIT: Modified the code above. You can use the `section` argument to identify the section you want to modify.

Comment: i get this error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: It Partially Works...Now all my sections have that header text but i want to only have header text in some of them, and customize the text to each one of them as well . + i want my original grey color if may i ask :D

Comment: @NewbieQuestions Updated the code to identify the section you need.

Comment: Ok Things look better now but there is still one more thing , The lable gets dots in the ends when my original text fit just right...Know how to fix this?

Comment: Updated code. Any further customizations you will need to ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127443/discussion-between-george-h-and-newbie-questions).

Comment: i sent you a couple of messege @George H

Comment: there are the dots like the text is discontinued
and i would like it to look like the first picture just with the new alignment.

Comment: There is this weird spacing that i dont know how to fix can you help?

Answer (score 26):

**Swift 4**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Your Header Name"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "YourFontname", size: 14.0)
    header.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
}
```

Comment: It works flawlessly! IMO this is better solution than the marked answer

Comment: thats the way I like it, native quick and easy 

Comment: For the newbies in this world, don't forget to call .delegate = self in your viewDidLoad
Example:          self.tableView.delegate = self